# Fastest way for updating: update() or save()?

Tags: php, mongodb

I loop through the documents of my collection, do some stuff, and then update the database. But as I actually have all the data of the document I'm updating, would save() be faster than of update() if I do it that way?

```
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
  $doc['new_field'] = 'value';
  $coll->save($doc);

  /* or (currently) */

  $coll->update(array('known_field' => $doc['known_field']), array('$set' => array('new_field' => 'value')));
}
```

Which way is faster?

Comment: How about benchmarking it yourself? It's really easy, just run the two variants a thousand times each and keep track of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::update` should be faster because it update only some fields of a document. `::save` save entire document and probably will slower.

In general better to use `::update` where it possible, because if you using `::save` possible concurrency problems. For example if two threads has loaded same document, update it and then trying to save. Lets say first thread has saved document. Then second thread rewrite changes of first thread and you lose updates of first thread. With atomic update you never get stuck on this problem.